# Unable to put <dialog> element into fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, dialog, html5-fullscreen

I can't seem to put a  element into fullscreen mode on Google Chrome with `requestFullscreen()`. I get a TypeError of "fullscreen error", which isn't all that helpful. This happens whether I use `showModal` or `show`, or neither. I usually give the modal `display: none` until it is opened, but I also tried without this style.

Other browsers allow the fullscreening. This includes at least Firefox, which supports `modal.show` but not `modal.showModal`, and Internet Explorer, which doesn't support `dialog` elements. The npm package `dialog-polyfill`, which I have been using, adds partial `<dialog>` support on these browsers, but doesn't affect which browsers allow or deny the fullscreening behavior.

Is the error part of the spec? I haven't been able to find too much info on the error, and both specs seem to allow the behavior, though I admit I'm not too proficient with reading browser specs. Are the other browsers allowing the fullscreening because they haven't fully implemented the dialog feature, or is this a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

On reading the spec a bit more, I found out that the  element isn't supposed to support fullscreen mode. The spec specifically states:

> The requestFullscreen(options) method, when invoked, must run these
>   steps:
>
> 6. If any of the following conditions are false, then set error to true:
>
>    - pending’s namespace is the HTML namespace or pending is an SVG svg or MathML math element. [SVG] [MATHML]
>    - **pending is not a dialog element.**
>    - The fullscreen element ready check for pending returns true.
>    - Fullscreen is supported.
>    - This algorithm is allowed to request fullscreen.

If anyone can provide more information on why this restriction exists, I would be very interested. It doesn't seem like a reasonable restriction, as the `dialog` element seems tailor-made to work well with fullscreen, as a way to isolate the dialog from the page even more.